# Which Knockout.js bindings are "Two-way"?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Knockout.js boasts two-way bindings, and the [live examples show](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) how the `value` binding (when applied to a text input) updates the viewmodel.

However, I've tried to update other bindings (like `text`) and found that the view does not update the viewmodel. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/w7t89tuu/

It's unclear from knockout's documentation whether some of their bindings are two-way and others are not. Under what conditions can the view update the viewmodel?

Comment: They are two-way... you're just not updating the value as you should. If you're going to do it programmatically, you change it via the bound observable. Otherwise you put the value in the input.  You went out and did something completely different...

Comment: You could try `.trigger('change')` if you're using jquery. I've used this in unit tests to test 'two-way' bindings on input elements.

Comment: @JeffMercado, are you saying that IF you want to update the view, and have it update the value, then you can only do that for inputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer

Two-way bindings: in general all the bindings related to something that the user can change directly, without the help of special scripts, like form control values or states: `value`, `hasFocus`, `textInput`, `checked`, `selectedOptions`. Or any custom binding related to something that the user can change (the typical example of 5 clickable stars implemented as a ko custom binding).

One-way bindings: all the states which cannot be directly changed by the user, for example `visible`. The user cannot change directly the visibility: it must be done via an script. In this case the script should not change the visibility of the DOM element itself, but should change the bound observable. The first wouldn't update the observable, but the latter would update the visibility of the bound element.

### Long answer

If you look how to implement custom bindings you'll understand how they work: [Creating custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
    // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
    // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
    // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
  }
};
```

If you look further you'll see what `init` callback can be used for:

> Knockout will call your init function once for each DOM element that you use the binding on. There are two main uses for init:
>
> 1.To set any initial state for the DOM element
>
> 2. To register any event handlers so that, for example, when the user clicks on or modifies the DOM element, you can change the state of the associated observable

The key is in the second point: if the binding handles some kind of event, it will modify the observable value, which is what you consider the "way back" of the "two-way binding".

So, any binding that handles events to update the observable work as "two-way" binding.

Comment: Well written and very helpful answer (+1). And it might also explain why Vue.js, which offers better two-way binding, is more populate now than Knockout.js.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're not updating the observable value, you're directly modifying the element's text. The [same thing happens](http://jsfiddle.net/w7t89tuu/4/) if you directly update the `input` element's value - you're not modifying the observable value at all. If you want to update the observable value, you can instead use:

```
this.changeName = function() {
    this.name('Bob');
};
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7t89tuu/3/).

Comment: Right, but doesn't this, by definition, make it a one-way binding? I must update the obseverable value in the data in order to update the view. Not the other way around?

Comment: @bryanbraun well yes, non-interactive elements aren't two-way binding - the `text` binding purely pulls text from an observable onto the page. You can't do anything with it. The `value` binding pulls the value from an observable into an interactive element on the page and updates the observable when value within the element is modified.

Comment: Cool, this is what I'm trying to get at. Do you know if it's documented which elements are "interactive"? Just form elements? Elements with `contenteditable="true"`? Also, do I only get the two-way binding if I use the value binding (not `text`, `attr`, `checked`, etc.)?

Comment: @bryanbraun From Knockout's documentation, the `value` binding is primarily targeted at `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements. The `checked` binding is also a two-way binding, but unfortunately this isn't mentioned on the page about the `checked` binding (it's instead mentioned on the `value` binding's page). As for `attr`, I'm not really sure why these would need to be two-way bindings as users aren't usually exposed to methods which allow them to change these themselves.