# How to bind input values in a foreach loop on knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a foreach loop set up to go through a list of objects and display them as input fields on the page but can't get the values to be saved to the object when the input is updated.  In the javascript I have:

```
$(function (carService, $) {
  var viewModel = function () {
    self = this;
    self.Vehicles = ko.observableArray();

    var vehicle = new Object();
    vehicle.VehicleMake = ko.observable("test make");
    vehicle.VehicleModel = ko.observable("test model");
    self.Vehicles.push(vehicle);
  }
  app.carService.viewModel = new viewModel();
  ko.mapping.fromJSON(settings.modelJson, {}, app.carService.viewModel);
});
```

I have data-bind to the values in a foreach data-bind loop:

```
<div data-bind="with:app.carService.viewModel">
  <div data-bind="foreach: Vehicles">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: VehicleMake, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: VehicleModel, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The data from the javascript object ("test make" and "test model) shows up in the input fields but when those inputs are changed that data is not reflected back to the object like it normally is with data bind.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do the orginal values come from? If such values come from a database, then drop a lsitview, repeater, or even a gridview on the page - fill it (takes about 4 lines of code), and now your data is rendered on the page - and those controls persist the data for you, including allowing user to change/edit values. You can then loop that repeater control and send the edit results back to the database. Using a server side control will chop your work by 5x in terms of markup- and also in terms of code that you have to write to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

- Try changing it to [TextInput](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html), knockout recommends TextInput two
  Binding over value binding,
- Also make sure you are binding to the [observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30055732/6085193) and not the
  input element's value

[image: Knockout Ref.]